# Combining an online database and a Facebook login

Tags: ios, facebook-login

I'm making an app and decided to go with a Facebook Login to log users into the app. This seems to be fairly easy, and Facebook has a great number of tutorials to use. 
However, I want to retrieve (from my online database) a certain set of information related to individual users when the user logs in. How would I go about that?

That includes creating a row in my database for that specific user when it's his first time logging into the app (equivalent of registering for the app), and then inserting and retrieving information in different columns on that row.

So to start, how would I store that user in the database? Normally I'd have a `user_id` linked up to a `username` and `password` combination, but this time I don't have neither a `username` nor a `password`. I can't use their name, as more there might be more than one person with a name. Does Facebook give access to their `user_id`? If so, how do I retrieve it? If not, how would I go about doing that?

All your help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Facebook [FBGraphUser](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ios/current/protocol/FBGraphUser) class provides access to basic user information including  `id` and `username` properties.  You don't say which method of logging in to Facebook you are using, but the Facebook Login Button/Login View calls the delegate method loginViewFetchedUserInfo:user where user is the FBGraphUser.

If you use the lower-level APIs then you will need to use the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/graph) to obtain the user information.

A sample delegate method would be -

```
- (void) loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
    NSLog(@"Facebook user id is %@ and user name is %@",user.id,user.username);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, just the answer I was looking for. Now how do I obtain the id from Facebook?

Comment: As I said in my answer, it depends on whether you are using the FBLoginView or lower-level APIs, but it is just a property of the FBGraphUser. I have updated my answer with an example delegate method for the FBLoginView